# jtools::plot_summs but for odds ratio - is this possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been using `jtools::plot_summs` to plot regression estimates for a series of logistic regression models. I have been asked to do this plot but using an odds ratio for reporting the coefficients. Is this possible? I've tried the following options with dummy data, but I don't entirely understand the [jtools documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf) and am uncertain if either the `exp = TRUE` or the `scale = TRUE` gets me what I need:

```r
library(jtools) 
library(ggstance)
library(broom.mixed)

data("mtcars")

mylogit.m1 <- glm(am ~ cyl, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")
mylogit.m2 <- glm(am ~ cyl + hp, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")
mylogit.m3 <- glm(am ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")

summary(mylogit.m1)
summary(mylogit.m2)
summary(mylogit.m3)

plot_summs(mylogit.m1, mylogit.m2, mylogit.m3, main.title = "Basic")
plot_summs(mylogit.m1, mylogit.m2, mylogit.m3, exp = TRUE, main.title = "exp option")
plot_summs(mylogit.m1, mylogit.m2, mylogit.m3, scale = TRUE, main.title = "scale option")
```

[image: default plot output]
default plot output

[image: exp = true plot output]
exp = true plot output

[image: scale= TRUE plot out]
scale= TRUE plot out